# Getopt::Long missing parameters

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I wrote a script that needs to get few arguments from the user, and I encountered a problem while trying to read my script arguments.

The script can get the `-type` for running the functions on one file type or can get the flag `-all` in order to run on all file types.

```
my $opt = GetOptions (
    'help|h' => \$help,
    'type=s' => \$type,
    'all'    => \$all,
);
```

I am trying to think about all the wrong options that a user can run and found that when the user is running `myscript.pl -type -all`, the module reads the `-all` as the `-type` string.

Is there any elegant way to avoid such a thing?

Answer (score 4):

Allow either `-type` or `-all`, but not both.  Alternatively, remove the `-all` option and if `-type` is followed by `all`, treat it as you're trying to treat `-all` now.

```
my $opt = GetOptions (
    'help|h' => \$help,
    'type=s' => \$type,
    'all'    => sub { $type = "all"; },
);
```

Comment: this is exactly what i did. I just wanted if there is a build-in solution inside the GetOpt::Long for such problems.

Comment: @user1494264 not really.  What would be the logic in specifying `-type` with `-all` anyway?

Comment: @user1494264, How would a "built-in" solution (as if callbacks aren't built-in???) be any more succinct?

Answer (score 2):

Use `'type:s'` instead of `'type=s'` and the value for -type will be optional. Elegant? I don't know, but it's perlish.